# Error when passing json object from react frontend to rails api

Tags: json, reactjs, paw

I'm trying to send my form data to rails api from my react frontend but [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFRD7.png)

This is my react code to handle form data

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.user= {};
  this.state = this.getInitialState();
}

getInitialState = () => {
     const initialState = {
       email: "",
       password: ""
     };
     return initialState;
 }

change = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};

onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.user = JSON.stringify(this.state)
  this.user = "{\"user\":" + this.user + "}"
  console.log(this.user);
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/v1/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: this.user
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.json());
  })

  this.setState(this.getInitialState());
}
```

This code gives the following string in console:

{"user":{"email":"test@user.com","password":"password123."}}

Rails:

```
class V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

def create

@user = User.new(user_params)

if @user.save
  render :create
else
  head(:unprocessable_entity)
 end
end
private

 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end
end
```

Doing the same on PAW gives positive results

[PAW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaaPT.png)

Please help. I've been trying to fix this for 2 days now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Judging from your error message,I think your rails don't receive your json data from the frontend.So try add "p params[:user]" to check date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
this.user = "{\"user\":" + this.user + "}"
```

It just look like json,but it's actually a string.You could use typeof to check it.

```
console.log(typeof this.user) //string
```

There are many options to solve this problem.Here is an example.

```
const users = {
  user: user
}
console.log(users)
const user_json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users))
console.log(typeof user_json)
```

Comment: Well this didn't quite work but this did.
const data = JSON.stringify({user: this.state})

But thanks for pointing out that data type. completely missed that