# How to send form data as json in React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to build a React front end on top of a Rails API and I am currently working on the registration form on React. Below is my attempt at handling the form submission.

```
 const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        phone_number
      }))
    })
      .then(resp => console.log(resp.json))

    setFirst("")
    setLast("")
    setEmail("")
    setPassword("")
    setPhone("")
  }
```

However, when I print out the params received from React, it is empty. Below is my Rails User create method.

```
def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            puts user_params
        if @user.save
                render json: @user.id, status: :created
                UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
            else
                render json: {errors: @user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        def destroy
            @user.destroy
        end
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597464/json-stringify-entire-form-data-with-reactjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037527/error-when-passing-json-object-from-react-frontend-to-rails-api) and a bunch of other places but they say pretty much the same thing. Wrap the body in JSON.stringify or JSON.parse or both. But it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use axios and qs stringifier:

```
npm i axios qs
```

then:

```
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";

axios.post(url,qs.stringify(your body))
```

Comment: So I should scrap the entire fetch?

Comment: yep axios is commonly used with react, easy to implement and understand.

Comment: Is there a reason why my method wasn't working? I was kinda following a tutorial.

Comment: did you try `JSON.stringify` only without `JSON.parse`